# .htaccess Wildcard subdirectory to single subdirectory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm looking to create a multi-tenant project with the address structure as follows

https://example.com/TENANTNAME/file.php
https://example.com/TENANTNAME/api/file.php
https://example.com/TENANTNAME/assets/js/main.js

And have it rewrite to a single subfolder, say /BASE/ - the idea being I can have a single set of files and then inspect the URL to figure out the rest.

Thank you

I did get it working to a point with the following, but further subfolders (Edited from subdomains) were not properly redirected, so the main index.php was fine but any anything in the assets folder was giving a server error

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/BASE/(.*)/
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ /BASE/$2 [L]
```

As an example, I would expect the following internal rewrites

https://example.com/TENANTNAME/index.php
to
https://example.com/BASE/index.php

https://example.com/TENANTNAME/assets/js/main.js
to
https://example.com/BASE/assets/js/main.js

The index.php example did work with my attempt however the assets example, with further subfolders, did not

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please invest time into revising your question (there is an "edit" button below it ...). Try to be more specific. You write "subdomains were not properly redirected" yet the code you added does not contain anything that handles "subdomains". Most likely that is a miss understanding, but you are the only one able to clear that up. A good idea is to add two or three easy examples to the question.

Comment: Does the `TENANTNAME` folder exist? if yes, then the rewrite conditions could match a file or directory, which would stop the rewrite rule to execute. So, I personally would remove these two rewrite conditions. I would also replace `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/BASE/(.*)/` by `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/BASE/` as you don't need to capture the second part of the path. And finally `RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.*)$ /BASE/$2?orig=$1 [L,QSA]` could be a way to get the original folder in the query string as useful information for your PHP scripts.

Comment: @PatrickJanser Amazing, thank you. That works perfectly. The TENANTNAME folder doesn't exist but appreciate they are unnecessary in what I'm trying to achieve. Could you add as an answer so I can mark as the accepted answer for anyone looking for similar please.

Answer (score 0):

#### 1. The test for existing files or directories

My first question was "*Could the wildcard folders exist on the disk?*"

If yes, then the first two rewrite conditions could potentially
stop the rewrite rule to execute when a request matches an existing file
or directory.

So I think you can remove these conditions, as you probably don't need
them.

#### 2. Testing the first part of the path

The next rewrite condition, testing that it's not the `/BASE/` root
directory, should be sufficient. But it can be slightly optimized by
replacing

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/BASE/(.*)/
```

By

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/BASE/
```

We don't need to capture what's behind the second slash. It actually
creates a variable called `%1` that can be used in the rewrite rule
destination URL. But in any case, we have some other capturing
groups in the rewrite rule pattern.

#### 3. Changing the rewrite rule pattern

They might be a little problem of greediness in the regex of the
rewrite rule. `^(.*)/` could be capturing to many characters,
leading to capturing some other slashes. So there are two solutions
to solve it:

- Make it ungreedy by adding a question mark: `^(.*?)/`
  By the way, I would replace the `*` by `+` because we want to
  match at least one char.
- Instead of the dot, use "*not a slash*": `^([^/]+)/`
  This has a big advantage because we know that a folder should not
  contain slash characters. The regex should run faster than the
  ungreedy version above and will also be safer.

Also, I thought that your PHP scripts might like to know what
was the original URL before the rewrites. You can get this
information by reading the `$_SERVER` array but why not converting
it to a query parameter as we captured it in any case? This can be
achieved this way:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.*)$ /BASE/$2?original_root=$1 [L,QSA]
```

The first capturing group is `$1` and can be added at the end of the
URL, as a query parameter. By the way, the rewrite rule pattern is
applied on the path without the query string (which is normally
added back to the destination URL). But here, as I am creating a
new query string, I have to enable the `QSA` option which will
append the original query string to the newly created one.
(QSA = **q**uery **s**tring **a**ppend).

This way, an URL like:

```
/any-folder/something/script.php?id=6&op=view
```

should become:

```
/BASE/something/script.php?original_root=any-folder&id=6&op=view
```